# How can SOLR serve documents with fields not stored in SOLR

Tags: solr, nosql

We have a client side facing solr server that needs to fetch additional fields from another data source for each document it returned.

Currently we are using Document Transformers but we would like to know is there any better way, especially on how to batch fetching the whole lot of data for all the documents in the current page of the query result.

Can a search component achieve this?

Comment: if you're using doc transformers, I assume that the values you are returning are constants. In such a case, have you tried configuring your solrconfig.xml file to return these results?

Comment: Why it need to be a constant to use doc transformer?

Comment: Sorry overlooked this thread. I'm not sure how you're using document transformers but as for your question it is possible to use a search component. Please see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a search component can achieve this.

But there are a few implications. The component can add a lot of latency of the external sources you're fetching from are slow to respond or if the fields are very large. This can affect your query response times very adversely.
You should consider loading your external fields into memory provided there are few of those and you have enough memory.

I've written an example on writing search components which you can find [here](https://github.com/lttazz99/SolrPluginsExamples).

An alternative, if the fields you add to the results don't depend on the queries, is to add these fields during index time itself using a custom update processor.